# Setting resizable to false in LibGDX

Tags: libgdx, graphics, window-management

I have a small working game prototype. I want to do something like

```
LwjglApplicationConfiguration cfg = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
cfg.resizable = false;
```

But I get "LwjglApplicationConfiguration cannot be resolved to a type"

What can I do? Or is there a different method?
Thanks.

Comment: where are you trying to use this code? Generally, the different sub projects (desktop, android, ios) have a launcher file that already has a cfg object defined. (Look at DesktopLauncher.java in the desktop project)

Comment: That was it. Thanks. This config code needs to be in -desktop/DesktopLauncher.java not the -´-core/MyGame !

Answer (score 1):

This code should work:

```
LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
config.resizable = false;
new LwjglApplication(new YourGame(), config);
```

Are you using the newest source from svn?
If it still doesn't work, there must be another problem..